# create GIF animation using Gmagick

Tags: php, animation, gif, animated-gif, gmagick

I have some jpg files i want to create gif animated from them. i cant find useful method in gmagick for this problem. any one know about it?

I need simple example for it. 
ty

Comment: Okay, I guess you are able to load the jpeg images, right? So the only problem would be to arrange the frames after each other (multi-page image) and save as gif. IIRC this is possible with Imagemagick so I guess it's possible as well with Graphicsmagick. Which of the many functions have you looked into so far?

Comment: Yeah. how can i load jpg files as frames, add as frame and duration also create infinite loop or loop time and standard creation GIF format using PHP script and Gmagick extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmagick example on how to create a GIF picture from two PNG files:

```
$first = new Gmagick("example.0.png");
$first->setImageformat("gif");
$first->setImageDelay(100);
$second = new Gmagick ("example.1.png");
$first->nextImage();
$first->addImage($second);
$first->previousImage();
$first->write('example.gif');
```

> *Example taken from https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59420*

Take care that [`Gmagick`](http://php.net/gmagick) internally keeps track at which image you are, that is why [`nextImage`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/gmagick.nextImage) is used before adding the second image and why [`previousImage`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/gmagick.previousImage) is used before writing it to disk.

Start with this two picture example and then change it to a version that adds pictures from an `array` and with three pictures. And then finally read the `array` from a directory from 0 to N pictures (e.g. with `glob`). Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

alone with run the next command  be can do

open the terminal of command in linux and write it

```
convert -delay 25 1.png  2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png 10.png -loop 0 animate.gif
```

you can to create the image with inkscape and export to .png .jpg or other format

Answer (score 0):

**Please Try..**

[Creating an Animated GIF image](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~dhyatt/supercomp/n401a.html)

[ImageMagick v6 Animation basics](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_basics/)